# \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstance not working File Update in REST API yii2

Tags: rest, file-upload, yii2, yii-rest

Hi Im using REST API in yii 2 `\yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstance` is not getting file in my function.for debugging purpose I tried with `$_FILES['asset']` its printing with values.but not getting file instance using `\yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstance`

```
$updateFile = $_FILES['asset']; //Printing values
$model->asset = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'asset'); //Not printing,its empty
```

What is the issues,I couldn't validate If i process the file with `$_FILES`.Any help would be grateful!! Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
getInstanceByName('asset');
```

Comment: Yep..its works!! but not validates ` $updateFile =UploadedFile::getInstanceByName( 'asset');
        if($model->validate() && $updateFile) {
            $updateFile->saveAs(Yii::getAlias('@app') . '/web/uploads/'.$updateFile->name);
            $model->asset = $updateFile->name;
        }else{
            $model->asset = $oldfile;
        }`

Answer (score 0):

Your data should come like `$_FILES['Your_Model_Name']['asset']` if you want to use `UploadedFile::getInstance` method. Try this, it will work.

```
$updateFile = $_FILES['User']['asset']; //Printing values
$model->asset = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'asset'); // Not printing, it's empty
```

Comment: since its rest API call,it doesn't mandatory to have $_FILES['User'],that can be as any name.

Comment: We can assign it like $model->asset = $_FILES['asset']; I dont think so this answer is helpful!!